# A geometric inequality to triangle $ABC$

Tags: inequality, contest-math

If $a, b, c$ be the sides of a triangle $ABC$, I have to prove that

$\sum\limits_{cycl}^{} (\frac {a}{b+c})^2 + \frac {3 A^2}{abcs} \ge \frac {9}{8}$

where $A,s$ the area and the semiperemeter. I tried to use the Ravi's substitution, but the inequality was then quite hard to solve. It might be a differente method. Thank you

Comment: Use the $uvw$ method.

Comment: Isn't this inequality equivalent to the one you asked in another [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2856029/)?

Comment: Yes of course, but he wants another method. See please better a starting post.

Comment: @Steven I found a proof by SOS, but it's very ugly.

Comment: Thank you @MichaelRozenberg, you are very strong